# How to rename a field used as foreignkey in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, request, foreign-keys, rename

How to rename a field used as a foreign key in MySQL?
I found a workaround, using phpMyAdmin:

1. Remove the constraint
2. Rename the field
3. Re-add the constraint on the field (the same field but renamed)

But maybe there is a way to do that in one SQL request...
Any idea?

Comment: Are you renaming the *referencing* (child) or the *referenced* (parent) field? You better just post example schema and the expected result.

Comment: What is your version? I can rename any column on any version but 5.5: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fcwpQLx7pH7gxQjfLH1tio/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could execute the following code, and make the necessary changes according to your column and table names.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_constraint_name;

ALTER TABLE table_name
CHANGE fk_column_name new_fk_column_name datatype;

ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_constraint_name
REFERENCES parent_table_name(pk_column_name_id);
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Isn't this the same as what he wrote in the question?

Comment: He mentioned wanting to do it in one SQL request. I'm figuring he's doing it manually instead of executing some code to do it in one go.

Comment: He described a 3-step process, and asked if there's a way to do it more easily. Your answer matches the 3 steps.

Comment: I don't even know such thing like "RENAME" in MySQL. It looks more like Oracle syntax. But I might be missing something.

Comment: Right. I decided to put `CHANGE` instead of `RENAME`.